# Prove there are two metrics on finite set X

Tags: metric-spaces

Suppose X is a finite set and we know that the number elements in X is $P^{2n}$
which  $P$ is prime number and $n$ is an arbitrary  natural number. Prove for every function $f:X \rightarrow X$ there are two metrics $d_1 , d_2$ on X such that for every $x_1,x_2 \in X$ we have $$d_1(x_1,x_2)<P^n \Longrightarrow d_2(f(x_1),f(x_2))<P^n$$

hint: I think $d_1$ is not important and you can define it easily and we have to focus on $d_2$.

hint: $d_1$ and $d_2$ are not discrete metric

Comment: What is a tow metric?

Comment: I think we can consider $d_1$ what ever we want but we have to prove there is $d_2$

Comment: You write "hint: $d_1$ and $d_2$ are not discrete metric". Every metric on a finite set is discrete.